# Advice Regarding UK Student Visa

Tags: united-kingdom

This year my contract in Saudi Arabia will be over. I intend to apply for a student visa to the UK when I return to Lebanon to do a teaching diploma. My question is: Will my Saudi bank account be accepted for my financial evidence, in addition to that I will provide a letter from my employer to prove the source of my funds and a copy of my residence permit in Saudi Arabia?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Make sure it is a bank issued statement. All evidence of sound funding is good evidence. I don't think that the residence permit is really necessary, but that may depend on how long you plan to study in the UK. Best to include that as well to show that you are applying through the appropriate consulate.

Comment: According to [ECB05: where to apply, the policy](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/where-to-apply-ecb05/ecb5-where-to-apply-the-policy), for certain visas it's necessary to apply in the country of residence, while for others one "should be present legally in the country or territory you’re applying from."  This implies that the residence permit will be necessary.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was necessary for a long-term student visa as well as the short-term visa.

Comment: My understanding is that it isn't necessary for the application *per se,* just to show that the applicant is applying through an appropriate consulate.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I've paraphrased that into the answer.